# how to get two values from a table in one row

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to get two values from the same row in the database, but my query reads all the passwords that match the table.

example:

Username: Max, password: 1234
Login: Alex, password: 5678

Otherwise, I try to log into Max's account by typing the password: 5678 and log into it without problems. This is the situation with Alex too, I know my request is so bad and I know it's a problem, I read all the passwords but I only need to read Max's password, how do I do that?

Query:

```
Query name = session.createQuery("SELECT username FROM Accounts WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT username FROM Accounts WHERE username = '" + user[2] + "')");
Query pass = session.createQuery("SELECT password FROM Accounts WHERE password = '" + user[3] + "'");
Query mail = session.createQuery("SELECT email FROM Accounts WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT email FROM Accounts WHERE email = '" + user[3] + "')");
```

Comment: Something like `Query name = session.createQuery("SELECT username, password, email FROM Accounts WHERE username = :username AND password = :password)");` -- and then bind the username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Elliot Frisch helped me, I solved this problem and added a loop to read everything I get and there was no error.

Query:

```
users = session.createQuery("SELECT username, password FROM Accounts WHERE username = '" + user[2] + "' and password = '" + user[3] + "'");
```

Cicle:

```
for (Object[] profile : data1) {
    u = (String)profile[0];
    p = (String)profile[1];
}
```

Comment: BEWARE -- This is vulnerable to SQL injection. `user[2] = "'; DROP TABLE Accounts; --`